# Database design

Tags: sql-server

I've a system, that have two types of users (Companies and individuals).all types have a shared set of properties but they differ in another. What is the best design merge all in one table that allows null for unmatched properties, or separate them in two tables related to a basic table with a one to one relationship.
Thanks.

Comment: Build a base table with the shared properties and the link to two separate tables with the unique properties. That would follow the normalization process I believe.

Comment: what's the number of different fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Performance-wise, this is a matter of tradeoff.

Selecting the properties from another table will require an additional `JOIN` (which is bad for performance) but keeps the main table smaller (which is good for performance).

`JOIN` is quite a costly operation, so unless you have, like, `200` of these properties (which will increase the table much), you better keep them in one table.

Separating the tables, however, will make your `CHECK` and `NOT NULL` constraints more simple.

Answer (score 3):

For better performance, Use one table for both, allow nulls for different properties and add a type attribute.

The one-one relationship (equvalent to subclassing in OO world) will make your schema more maintainable and wasier to understand, but involves a performance hit. Choose your pill.